# 3.3 V through a 2 m cable : can it work?

Tags: power-supply, cables

I have to develop a system composed of 2 PCBs :

- The 1st PCB is supplied by a 3.7 V LiPo battery. A 3.3V DC-DC converter converts the battery voltage to 3.3 V to all components on this PCB (microcontroller, LED, etc.).
- The 2nd PCB includes sensors. It receives the supply from the 1st PCB. It is about 2 meters away from the 1st PCB, they are connected via a cable.

I was thinking of passing the 3.3 V output of the DC-DC converter through the cable from the 1st PCB to the 2nd PCB, and using a boost converter on the 2nd PCB to ensure that I have 3.3 V in the end.

Is that the right way to do it? I am afraid of the voltage drop due to the cable. Is the boost converter necessary? Would you consider adding extra components or using a different method to supply the 2nd PCB?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: "*I am afraid of the voltage drop due to the cable.*" Don't be afraid; do the calculations. Work out the current you require it to carry, your cable resistance (remembering to include the return path) and you can work out the voltage drop along the cable from V = I R.

Comment: I don't think that there'll be significant drop but there's more important thing to consider before that: Noise. That long cable may pick up a lot of noise from outside world. And you don't want to supply the sensitive devices with this "dirty" voltage.

Comment: You will get serious EMI issues with Boost converter, Beef up EMI on interfaces. heavy guage twisted pair , low ESR bulk caps near 3.3V load or use CM choke

Comment: Often you can just run 3.3V from one board to another board using wires. It just depends on how much current is required and how thick the wires are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage at the second PCB can be calculated through

$$ V_{2nd,PCB}  = V_{3V3} - 2 \cdot I_{2nd,PCB} \cdot \frac{l_{cable}\cdot \rho}{A_{cable}}  $$

Where $$ \rho  \approx 1.7 \cdot 10^{-8} \Omega m$$

If your second PCB's lower supply voltage threshold is alright with this voltage drop, you should not worry about it. Just make sure to add some additional capacitance at the input of the second PCB in order to cope with high transients (The cabble adds additional inductance).

Comment: You mean ohm/meter rather than ohm.meter, right?

Comment: Shouldn't the drop be multiplied by 2? Since there are two cables (postive rail and return), the current will drop a voltage across both of them.

Comment: @jcaron result's unit should be [Ohm]. Denominator's unit is [m²]. So Rho's unit should be [Ohm.m].

Comment: @RohatKılıç you're right, I will amend the answer.

Comment: FYI, wire cross-sectional areas can be found here: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/awg-wire-gauge-d_731.html  They are mm^2, so you need to divide by 10^6 to get m^2.

Comment: Your answer (in particular, the value of ρ) assumes copper. Perhaps it's best to make that assumption explicit, since stuff like cca and ccs exists.

Answer (score 0):

### Raid the mains electrical parts bin

Get yourself plain old commodity line cord (or if a permanent non-moving installation, twin-and-earth) of common size like 1.0mm2, 1.5mm2, 2.5mm2 or 4.0mm2.

They make enough of that wire to circle the earth every day, and so it's dirt cheap thanks to economies of scale.

You can go look up the resistance per metre on those various sizes of wire and compute voltage drop (resistance/metre x 2A x 4 metres), but at 2 amps and 2 metres round trip, it will be negligible.